# High water level in toilet bowl after flushing

Tags: toilet

How can I lower the water level in the bowl of a comfort height Kohler 1.6l flush with canister valve?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What problem are you trying to solve? Have you checked out Kohler's video on [adjusting the canister valve](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-EIbkkKhFxI&list=PLd2TSsbDn0gDwFr4qm4LqbEW1WOV8i41r)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't adjust the bowl water depth - it's set by the height of the trap that's cast into the bowl.  However, you can adjust the water depth in the **tank** as suggested by @Daniel Griscom.

[image: toilet bowl cross-secion]

There also might be an obstruction in the trap that's artificially raising the height.  Plunge and/or snake should take care of that.